# Placing element to the middle of a parent but leave text left aligned

Tags: css, html

How do a place and element to the middle of a parent. But I still want text to be aligned to the left. Fiddle with text aligned to the middle:

```css
.align-text{
  text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="col-xs-4">
         <div class="align-text">
             <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
             <div>text</div>
             <div>address</div>
         </div>
    </span>
    <span class="col-xs-4">
         <div class="align-text">
             <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
             <div>text</div>
             <div>address</div>
         </div>
    </span>
    <span class="col-xs-4">
         <div class="align-text">
             <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
             <div>text</div>
             <div>address</div>
         </div>
    </span>
```

everything works fine, I only want text to be aligned to the left not to the middle.

Comment: In your fiddle, the text is aligned to the left for me.

Comment: I forgot to save the fiddle, check it now :)

Comment: Now I see three columns with the text aligned to the left of each column.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve here from your fiddle?

Comment: i fixed it now..., forgot to add css to it

Comment: Note that while common practice (apparently), nesting a `<div>` inside a `<span>` is not valid HTML. It will most likely work in all browsers, it's not good practice.

Comment: Please include the relevant code from your fiddle here, if possible ([you can use the Stack Snippets feature](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)). Some people are barred from jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @papakia I want text to be in the middle, but not center aligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to center the text container in its parent and then left align its content.

Using `display: inline-block` in the text container and `text-align: center` to its parent center it.

Then you use `text-align: left` to left align your text content:

```
 <section class="col-xs-4">
     <div class="align-text">
         <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
         <div>text</div>
         <div>address</div>
     </div>
</section>
<section class="col-xs-4">
     <div class="align-text">
         <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
         <div>text</div>
         <div>address</div>
     </div>
</section>
<section class="col-xs-4">
     <div class="align-text">
         <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
         <div>text</div>
         <div>address</div>
     </div>
</section>

section
{
    text-align: center;
}

section > div 
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6051/

Answer (score 0):

Just use text-align left on the heading tags or whatever you want to align centre, the rest will initial align to the left:

```css
/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.align-text h3 {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
<span class="col-xs-4">
     <div class="align-text">
         <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
         <div>text</div>
         <div>address</div>
     </div>
</span>
<span class="col-xs-4">
     <div class="align-text">
         <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
         <div>text</div>
         <div>address</div>
     </div>
</span>
<span class="col-xs-4">
     <div class="align-text">
         <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
         <div>text</div>
         <div>address</div>
     </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexible boxes:

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="align-text">
    <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>address</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="align-text">
    <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>address</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="align-text">
    <div><h3>Sample</h3></div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>address</div>
  </div>
</div>
```